# C++ How to take value from EXE + Pointer + Offset + Offset?

Tags: c++, pointers, cheat-engine

I'm learning to modifying game values using C++ but now I'm stuck.

I know how to edit for example FLOAT value of Player speed:

```
uintptr_t _EntitiesBase = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(L"EntitiesMP.dll");
uintptr_t EntityBase = _EntitiesBase + 0x3153D0;
DWORD Run = 0xDE4;
*(FLOAT*)(*(DWORD*)EntityBase + Run) = Value;
```

But I don't know, how to edit values, that have much offsets (Engine.dll + 0xD52AB0 + 0x48 + 0x228), because in the end it return wrong value, not that I wanted to change

For example, in Cheat Engine, the same thing looks like this:

[image: like that:]

I added Engine.dll + 0xD52AB0 as a pointer, and next add offset 0x48 and offset 0x220 and it gives me address 2DC7E488, that contains FLOAT value, that I need to change

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I'm skeptical that the memory locations of the values you want to edit are consistent between program runs. In the past that used to be because games used a C/C++ global to store game or player-state, which would have predictable and consistent memory locations at runtime, but modern games and engines have much better internal engineering (pun not intended) and so won't be like that. And if it's a Java/JVM or .NET game then the offsets will change _as the program runs_ due to the GC moving objects in-memory (to reduce heap fragmentation).

Comment: Based on the screenshot you showed, it looks like the `baseAddr + 0xD52AB0` refers to a struct that contains a pointer at offset 0x48.  So you would need to pull a _pointer value_ from that address (`baseAddr + 0xD52AB0 + 0x48`) and then dereference it for the next address.  That then points to another structure somewhere else in memory and the data you want to modify is at offset 0x220 from that pointer.

Comment: In short: `*(float*)(*(uintptr_t*)(_EntitiesBase + 0xD52AB0 + 0x48) + 0x220) = Value;`

Comment: I've tried it, but nope, it doesn't work =(

Comment: ASLR is probably going to mess this up for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) to read process memory and [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory) to write process memory. to do this you just need to use [ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) for every offset then write the pointer value with [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory):-

```
uintptr_t entitybase;
uintptr_t value1;
float newValue = 100000;
ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, (uintptr_t)EngineDllHandle + 0xD52AB0, &entitybase, sizeof(entitybase), 0);
ReadProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, entitybase + 0x48, &value1, sizeof(value1), 0);
WriteProcessMemory(ProcessHandle, value1 + 0x220, &newValue, sizeof(entitybase), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uintptr_t FindDynamicAddy(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets)
{

    uintptr_t addr = ptr;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); ++i)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)addr, &addr, sizeof(addr), 0);
        addr += offsets[i];
    }
    return addr;
}
```

You can use function above to achieve that, You would need Process handle, for EntitiesMP.dll you could use windows.h api OpenProcess to achieve that.

For Ptr which is Pointer, so You would need EntitiesMP.dll + D52AB0

Above function will work!